# Find file in Linux then report the size of file searched

Tags: linux, find, size

How can i search for file in Linux then report the size of those file i have found ?

For example, i want to search file named core.txt in my home directory in Linux, core.txt also appear on some sub-directory under my home dir. Then after found core.txt, the command should also show me file size of those files have founded.

Cheers

Comment: `find . -type f -name core.txt -printf '%s %p\n'`

Answer (score 71):

We can use `find` command to find the file and `du -sh` to find out its size.

We will execute du -sh on found files. So final command would be

`find ~ -name "core.txt" -exec du -sh {} \;`
or
`find ~ -name "core.txt" | xargs du -sh`

In 2nd command `xargs` will not handle spaces in file name. So We can tell exact delimiter to xargs to handle spaces in file name.

`find ~ -name "core.txt" | xargs -d '\n' du -sh`

Comment: The first code sample doesn't work if there are spaces in any of the file names.

Comment: I have updated answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Rather use -print0 for find and -0 for xargs to make sure all strange file names are handed correctly.

Comment: are you able to explain the "{} \;" in the first command? Thanks!